# Proxy to remove TLS

Tags: tls, proxy, sniffer

I tried to sniff HTTP connections via Fiddler, which acts as a HTTP proxy. But the site is redirecting http requests to https. Is there a way to prevent this, either with fiddler or with any other windows software? For example downloading it though TLS and serving it in plaintext.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you need to solve with this? Fiddler should have no issues to decrypt the SSL traffic.

Comment: @Arminius As far the client doesn't check the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to sniff HTTP connections via Fiddler, which acts as a HTTP
>   proxy. But the site is redirecting http requests to https.

Fiddler will also act as a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) proxy in order to decrypt, read, and re-encrypt HTTPS requests.  According to the [Fiddler HTTPS Decryption](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) page:

> The decryption feature is disabled by default.... Enable the traffic
>   decryption option by clicking Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS and
>   ticking the Decrypt HTTPS Traffic box.

As with any MITM solution, the problem is that the client will not trust the certificate that Fiddler generates (because it is not signed by a legitimate CA).  The page linked above describes different methods to instruct your browser to trust the Fiddler CA, which will allow you to MITM your browser's connections without your browser distrusting the certificate.

(I assume from your description and the fact that you're using Fiddler that it's your own browser session you're trying to trace.  If that is the case, trusting the Fiddler certificate should be straightforward and easy.  If you're trying to snoop on *someone else's* browser, it is more difficult, as well as being subject to legal constraints.  However, many large organizations do this (legally) with web proxies such as Websense, and distribute the bespoke CA certificate via standard administration channels.)

Comment: Who said it's a browser or software on same PC at all? It can be another device as well where installation of certificates can be hard or impossible. So the way described in the question may be a better option.